# How to fix files and directories in Mac terminal from being inverted?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, osx-yosemite, terminal.app

I recently was going through some directories and realized that my files/directories are inverted as opposed to being alphabetic from top to bottom.
As the terminal is after an ls -al:

- Public
- Pictures
- Music
- ...
- Applications
- AndroidStudioProjects
- .viminfo
- ... and so on

I wish to reverse it to alphabetic top to bottom, the way it was before.

It shows up alphabetically in Finder and I have searched through Terminal settings and have not been able to find an answer anywhere. Does anyone know how to fix this annoyance?

**Edit:**
I know it's been a while, but I'm adding my *~/.bash_profile* to this to see if it will help anyone help me with this issue. I do not feel like anything in here would affect my inverted files/directories, but I thought I'd include it just in case people have any suggestions.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/smlnj-110.77/bin"
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
alias sublime="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app"
alias ls='ls -color'
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
alias mongod="sudo /Applications/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.0.4/bin/mongod"
alias mongo="sudo /Applications/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.0.4/bin/mongo"
```

I appreciate any help that can be given,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved my issue**

The reason for the inverting of my files and directories is due to the `ls -color`. Tested and it was due to the **r** in ls -colo**r**, so it was using **-r** of **ls** reversing the order. I don't know where I first started using `ls -color`, maybe in one of my other dot files from my Linux computer, but that was the problem in the end, so I ended up just removing the `ls -color` as it did not do what I used to think it did, as well as fixing my inverting issue.

Comment: See, I told ya :P

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ls -r
```

Read

```
man ls
```

Look at

```
~/.bash_profile 
/etc/bashrc
```

and similar files that may override default ls settings (could be a BASH alias or something like that.)

You can also try to log in as Guest and check if the problem remains. If not, this must be a user-level setting in which case you need to examine files like .bash_profile in $HOME directory of your account. If the problem is still there it is a system-wide configuration, most likely, and you should be looking at /etc.

Comment: I read through the ls manual and doesn't seem like anything in their would change it. I tried ls -r and it gave me the same thing. I've double checked my bash_profile and at /etc/bashrc, and none of it seems like it would cause this.
I logged in as a guest and the problem does not remain though, so it must be somewhere connected to this account.

Comment: That's so weird but as you can see something is messing up your default settings. You can always recreate an account but that's going to be somewhat tedious.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping not to go that far. I just finished resetting terminal to default settings, in the shell settings and no luck. I feel at this rate, my best chance is when I do a fresh install once El Capitan is released.